# How to Group time segments and check break time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stored function that pulls all employee clock in information.  I'm trying to pull an exception report to audit lunches.  My current query builds all info 1 segment at a time.

```
SELECT        ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sFirstName, ftc.sLastName, ftc.dtTimeIn,
              ftc.dtTimeOut, ftc.TotalHours, ftc.PunchedIn, ftc.Edited
FROM          dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList,
                            @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc
              LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees AS e ON ftc.lEmployeeID = e.lEmployeeID
WHERE        (ftc.TotalHours >= 0) AND (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) OR
                         (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) AND (ftc.dtTimeOut IS NULL)
```

The output for this looks like this:

```
24  Bob bibby   8/2/2013 11:55:23 AM    8/2/2013 3:36:44 PM 3.68
24  bob bibby   8/2/2013 4:10:46 PM 8/2/2013 8:14:30 PM 4.07
39  rob blah    8/2/2013 8:01:57 AM 8/2/2013 5:01:40 PM 9.01
41  john    doe 8/2/2013 10:09:58 AM    8/2/2013 1:33:38 PM 3.4 
41  john    doe 8/2/2013 1:55:56 PM 8/2/2013 6:10:15 PM 4.25
```

I need the query to do 2 things.

1) group the segments together for each day.
2) report the "break time" in a new colum

After I have that info I need to check the hours of each segment and make sure 2 things happen.

1) if they worked over a total of 6 hours, did they get a 30 minute break?
2) if they took a break, did they take a break > 30 minutes.

You see that Bob punched in at 11:55 AM and Punched out for lunch at 3:36.  He punched back in from lunch at 4:10 and punched out at 8:14.  He worked a total of 7.75 hours, and took over a 34 minute break.
He was OK here. and I don't want to report an exception

John worked a total of 7.65 hours.  However, when he punched out, he only took 22 minute lunch.  I need to report "Jim only took 22 minute lunch"

You will also see rob worked 9 hours, without a break.  I need to report "rob Worked over 6 hours and did not take a break"

I think if I can accomplish grouping the 2 segments.  Then I can handle the reporting aspect.

*UPDATE**

I changed the query to try to accomplish this.  Below is my current query:

```
SELECT        ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sFirstName, ftc.sLastName, ftc.TotalHours, DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) AS Break_Time_Minutes
FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Employees AS e ON ftc.lEmployeeID = e.lEmployeeID
WHERE        (ftc.TotalHours >= 0) AND (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) OR
                         (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) AND (ftc.dtTimeOut IS NULL)
GROUP BY ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sFirstName, ftc.sLastName, ftc.TotalHours
```

My Output currently looks like this:

```
24  Bob bibby   3.68    -221
24  bob bibby   4.07    -244
39  rob blah    0.05    -3
39  rob blah    2.63    -158
41  john    doe 3.4 -204
41  john    doe     4.25    -255
```

As you can see It's not combining the segments by date and the Break_time is displaying negative minutes.  It's also not combining the days.  Bob's time should be on 1 line.  and display 7.75 minutes break-time should 34 minutes.

Comment: first you use datediff(minute,outtime,intime) to get one more column.
then again sum the datediff group by username.
then use case statement for remarks.Show data in correct format aong with column name.

Comment: I have to combine the segments... I only want to report those who have taken a break less than 30 minutes, including those who didn't take one at all.  I also need to report the total number of hours they worked without an adequate break

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i believe if you want to combine both times you need to take them out of the group by and add sum them. based on the results the reporting can check total hours and break hours. you can add case statements if you want to flag them.

```
SELECT  ftc.lEmployeeID
       ,ftc.sFirstName
       ,ftc.sLastName
       ,SUM(ftc.TotalHours) AS TotalHours
       ,DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) AS BreakTimeMinutes
FROM dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate,
                   @DeptList, @iActive,@ EmployeeList) AS ftc
WHERE SUM(ftc.TotalHours) >= 0 AND (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) OR
                     (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) AND (ftc.dtTimeOut IS NULL)
GROUP BY ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sFirstName, ftc.sLastName
```

I made this quick test in sql and it appears to work the way you want. did you add something to the group by?

```
declare @table table (emp_id int,name varchar(4), tin time,tout time);

insert into @table
VALUES (1,'d','8:30:00','11:35:00'),
    (1,'d','13:00:00','17:00:00');


SELECT t.emp_id
      ,t.name
      ,SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, tin,tout))/60 as hours
      ,DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(tout), MAX(tin)) AS BreakTimeMinutes
FROM @table t

GROUP BY t.emp_id, t.name
```

Comment: This combines them, but doesn't fix the breaktimeminutes.  It still displays the breaktime minutes as the total minutes worked for that day.  For example.  the first employee worked 7.75 hours.  I moved the SUM(FTC.TOTALHOURS) to a having clause btw.  Breaktime shows "465" minutes for breaktime...

Comment: oh i see you need the time between the first records end time and the next records begin time.

Comment: i edited to use the max time in and min timeout, if they come back as negative you can just switch the two parameters i think.

Comment: This separates the hours again, and displays the break time as the first segment, then the second segment

Comment: if there are ever more than 2 records per emp the breaktimeminutes will not work though.

Comment: Most of the time, there is only 2 records.

Comment: i added an example to my answer where the group by and aggregates are working as expected. not sure why yours is splitting it out into two records unless you have more than id and names in the group by.

Comment: I have altered your query a touch.  I can tell you what I did and accept your answer.  I literally changed a few things on your initial query.

Comment: yah i'm curious. the example i made worked. just tough to test yours without the function and tables.

Comment: Here is what I used: 'SELECT        lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName, SUM(TotalHours) AS TotalHours, DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(dtTimeOut), MAX(dtTimeIn)) AS BreakTimeMinutes
WHERE        (DID IS NOT NULL) OR
                         (DID IS NOT NULL) AND (dtTimeOut IS NULL)
GROUP BY lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName'

Comment: I changed your second datediff statement.  I added the MIN and MAX.  You were summing all of the hours again, which was basically a repeat of total hours.  I left the from statement out because the "@" were not allowed in a comment.  Although now I see your MIN and MAX.  I also removed the total hours >= 0.

Comment: hmm that looks like what i have after the edit. anyways glad its working.

Comment: Where would I add the case statements? it doesn't detect "Breaktime" as a valid column

Comment: you would need to use the aggregates.

Comment: CASE WHEN SUM(ftc.TotalHours) > 6 AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BadBoyBreaksToLong,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43627/discussion-between-shmewnix-and-bozman)

Answer (score 2):

Using the pertinent pieces of your sample SQL, I created an SQL Fiddle showing how this could be done.  You can view it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f05ce/3

```
SELECT EmployeeId, Num_Hours, 
 CASE WHEN tmp.Break_Time_Minutes < 0 Then 0 Else Break_Time_Minutes END As Break_Time_Minutes, 
 CASE WHEN tmp.Break_Time_Minutes < 0 Then 1 Else 0 END As SkippedBreak
 FROM (
 SELECT EmployeeId, 
 Round(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, TimeIn, TimeOut) / 60.0 / 60.0),1) As NUM_Hours,
 DateDiff(mi, Min(TimeOut), Max(TimeIn)) As Break_Time_Minutes  FROM Employee 
  GROUP BY EmployeeId, CAST(TimeIn As Date)
) as tmp WHERE tmp.Num_Hours > 6 AND Break_Time_Minutes < 30
```

Comment: Help is much appreciated.  The problem is, my info doesn't exist as a table so I can't access it directly.  The info comes from a function.  I need to be able to run your query off of my query, all within the same query.  I can't do a stored procedure because the database's are synced and I do not have access to changed the synced info.

Comment: You can just use your initial query as a subquery.  Where I have written "FROM Employee" above, have this say "FROM (your-query-here) as Employee"

Comment: Sorry, I tried that and have altered this in may ways.  I'm unable to get the query's to work together.  I believe my joins and where statements may be conflicting with the way you are searching and sorting.  I've tried to alter that as well, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

### Self-Contained Example:

Here is an example of how this would work.
I used stand-alone logic that is not dependent on your custom-built function because the community here does not have access to it (including the data it uses).
Instead I built my answer off of the "*output*" you managed to supply.
This will run self-contained because there are no object-dependencies.

```
DECLARE @EmpClock Table
(
    EmployeeID Int,
    FirstName  VarChar(50),
    LastName   VarChar(50),
    PunchIn    DateTime,
    PunchOut   DateTime
)
INSERT INTO @EmpClock
    SELECT 24,'Bob','bibby','8/2/2013 11:55:23 AM','8/2/2013 3:36:44 PM' UNION
    SELECT 24,'bob','bibby','8/2/2013 4:10:46 PM','8/2/2013 8:14:30 PM' UNION
    SELECT 39,'rob','blah','8/2/2013 8:01:57 AM','8/2/2013 5:01:40 PM' UNION
    SELECT 41,'john','doe','8/2/2013 10:09:58 AM','8/2/2013 1:33:38 PM' UNION
    SELECT 41,'john','doe','8/2/2013 1:55:56 PM','8/2/2013 6:10:15 PM' UNION
    SELECT 1,'Mike','TeeVee','8/2/2013 12:05:30 PM','8/2/2013 2:15:45 PM' UNION
    SELECT 1,'Mike','TeeVee','8/2/2013 2:25:05 PM','8/2/2013 3:35:25 PM' UNION
    SELECT 1,'Mike','TeeVee','8/2/2013 3:50:15 PM','8/2/2013 5:30:55 PM' UNION
    SELECT 1,'Mike','TeeVee','8/2/2013 5:40:35 PM','8/2/2013 6:50:20 PM'
SELECT *,
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, '', EC.WorkedTotal)/60.0/60.0[WorkedHours],
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, '', EC.BreakTotal )/60.0     [BreakMinutes]
  FROM
  (
    SELECT EC.*,
           DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, WorkedTotal, WorkPeriod), CAST('' as Time(0)))[BreakTotal]
      FROM
      (
        SELECT EC.EmployeeID, EC.EmployeeName, EC.Day,
               DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, EC.FirstPunchIn, EC.LastPunchOut), CAST('' as Time(0)))[WorkPeriod],
               DATEADD(SECOND, EC.Worked, CAST('' as Time(0)))[WorkedTotal]
          FROM
          (
            SELECT EC.EmployeeID,
                   (EC.FirstName + ' ' + EC.LastName)[EmployeeName],
                   --"Day" Assumes Punches do not span across midnight.
                   --  If any do, then the day of the Punch-In will be used.
                   CAST(EC.PunchIn as Date)[Day],
                   SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, EC.PunchIn, EC.PunchOut))[Worked],
                   MIN(EC.PunchIn)[FirstPunchIn],
                   MAX(EC.PunchOut)[LastPunchOut]
              FROM @EmpClock as EC
             GROUP BY EC.EmployeeID, (EC.FirstName + ' ' + EC.LastName), CAST(EC.PunchIn as Date)
          ) AS EC
      ) AS EC
  ) AS EC
 WHERE EC.BreakTotal  > DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, CAST('' as Time(0)))
   AND EC.WorkedTotal > DATEADD(HOUR,    6, CAST('' as Time(0)))
```

### Results:

Notice I added more data to it for a fictional employee named "*Mike TeeVee*".
I did this in case you have an employee that spaces out their breaks or needed an emergency break for whatever reason.
This allows us to test how the logic handles cases like these.

Without the Where-Clause at the end, we would see this:
[image]

Run as-is (with the Where-Clause) and you will see it properly filters out the results:
[image]

You will notice that I show both the Time-DataType format of the results as "*WorkedTotal*" and "*BreakTotal*".  I prefer this for display purposes as we typically do not think of hours as fractions of a whole 100%, but instead as both hours and remainder-minutes.

I went ahead and included the fraction-hours and fraction-minutes as "*WorkedHours*" and "*BreakMinutes*" respectively in case your requirements needed them in that format for further calculations.

The "*WorkPeriod*" represents how long the shift was (including break-time).
I'm sure you do not need this information, but I included it for completeness.

### Using Your Own Logic:

Judging by the other answers here I see you are having problems incorporating your logic into their answers, so I did that for you too.
The script below will only run in your environment:

```
SELECT *,
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, '', EC.WorkedTotal)/60.0/60.0[WorkedHours],
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, '', EC.BreakTotal )/60.0     [BreakMinutes]
  FROM
  (
    SELECT EC.*,
           DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, WorkedTotal, WorkPeriod), CAST('' as Time(0)))[BreakTotal]
      FROM
      (
        SELECT EC.EmployeeID, EC.EmployeeName, EC.Day,
               DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, EC.FirstPunchIn, EC.LastPunchOut), CAST('' as Time(0)))[WorkPeriod],
               DATEADD(SECOND, EC.Worked, CAST('' as Time(0)))[WorkedTotal]
          FROM
          (
            SELECT EC.EmployeeID,
                   (EC.FirstName + ' ' + EC.LastName)[EmployeeName],
                   --"Day" Assumes Punches do not span across midnight.
                   CAST(EC.PunchIn as Date)[Day],
                   SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, EC.PunchIn, EC.PunchOut))[Worked],
                   MIN(EC.PunchIn)[FirstPunchIn],
                   MAX(EC.PunchOut)[LastPunchOut]
              FROM
              ( --I replaced my table variable @EmpClock with a call to your own logic.
                SELECT EC.lEmployeeID[EmployeeID], EC.sFirstName[FirstName], EC.sLastName[LastName],
                       EC.dtTimeIn[PunchIn], EC.dtTimeOut[PunchOut]
                       --You have these in your original query, but the values are missing in your "output".
                       --,EC.TotalHours, EC.PunchedIn, EC.Edited
                  FROM dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) as EC
                  LEFT JOIN Employees as E
                    ON EC.lEmployeeID = E.lEmployeeID
              ) AS EC
             GROUP BY EC.EmployeeID, (EC.FirstName + ' ' + EC.LastName), CAST(EC.PunchIn as Date)
          ) AS EC
      ) AS EC
  ) AS EC
 WHERE EC.BreakTotal  > DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, CAST('' as Time(0)))
   AND EC.WorkedTotal > DATEADD(HOUR,    6, CAST('' as Time(0)))
```

### Possible Bug:

I also noticed a problem in your where-clause:

```
 WHERE (ftc.TotalHours >= 0) AND (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) OR
       (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) AND (ftc.dtTimeOut IS NULL)
```

It is unclear what you are trying to "*OR*" here and you have "*ftc.DID IS NOT NULL*" listed twice.
You may want to review that logic and consider using your parenthesis properly when using OR.
Because of this confusion, I have omitted this logic in my example above.

Did you by chance mean this instead?:

```
 WHERE ftc.DID IS NOT NULL
   AND (ftc.TotalHours >= 0 OR ftc.dtTimeOut IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 SELECT ftc.lEmployeeID,sum(ftc.TotalHours)as TotalHours,
 ABS(DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(convert(datetime,ftc.dtTimeOut,9)), MAX(convert(datetime,ftc.dtTimeIn,9)))) AS Break_Time_Minutes

   FROM dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Employees AS e ON ftc.lEmployeeID = e.lEmployeeID
   WHERE (ftc.TotalHours >= 0) AND (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) OR
      (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) AND (ftc.dtTimeOut IS NULL)


group by ftc.EmployeeiD,DATE(ftc.dtTimeIn)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be quite right.  It throws multiple errors as I try to correct your query

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to write here.content may be long .
your problem still not solve yet it appear to be easy because you are imposing **dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList)** on us.
we don't know if ftc.TotalHours is already sum of something or what it is .
all you do is show table structure and some data in table variable.your explanation is good enuf .
secondly i would like to point out is you never do **group by id,firstname,lastname**.
**group by** id is more than enough.So in your case you need CTE.i cannot write whole query coz something is table and data is not clear .

```
;with CTE as
(SELECT ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sFirstName, ftc.sLastName, ftc.dtTimeIn, ftc.dtTimeOut, ftc.TotalHours, ftc.PunchedIn, ftc.Edited
FROM    dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Employees AS e ON ftc.lEmployeeID = e.lEmployeeID
WHERE   (ftc.TotalHours >= 0) AND (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) OR
    (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) AND (ftc.dtTimeOut IS NULL)
)
,CTE1 as
(
SELECT        ftc.lEmployeeID

          ,SUM(ftc.TotalHours) AS TotalHours
           MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut) MindtTimeOut, MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn) AS MAXdtTimeIn
FROM dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc

WHERE SUM(ftc.TotalHours) >= 0 AND (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) OR
                     (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) AND (ftc.dtTimeOut IS NULL)
GROUP BY ftc.lEmployeeID
)
,CTE2 as
(
 join cte and cte1 on employeeid--well it depend
)
select * from cte2--this is just indicative.
```

Answer (score 1):

with a CTE to group segments, you can query this CTE to check for break duration.
Add other checks in the final `CASE WHEN` statement :

```
; with
DailyRecords as 
(   -- add a rownumber to each entry by employee/day
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ftc.lEmployeeId, cast(ftc.dtTimeIn as date)
                            order by ftc.lEmployeeId, ftc.dtTimeIn ) as rownum,
        cast(ftc.dtTimeIn as date) as [Day],
        ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sFirstName, ftc.sLastName, ftc.dtTimeIn, ftc.dtTimeOut, ftc.TotalHours
    from fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) ftc
),
DailyRequest as
(   -- group 2 segments together (rownum 1 and 2), and report break time in a new column
    select Segment1.lEmployeeId, Segment1.sFirstName, Segment1.sLastName, 
        Segment1.[Day], 
        coalesce(round(datediff(mi,Segment1.dtTimeIn, Segment1.dtTimeOut) / 60.0, 2),0) as Duration1,
        coalesce(round(datediff(mi,Segment2.dtTimeIn, Segment2.dtTimeOut) / 60.0, 2), 0) as Duration2,
        coalesce(round(datediff(mi,Segment1.dtTimeOut,Segment2.dtTimeIn),2),0)  as BreakDuration
    from DailyRecords Segment1
    left join DailyRecords Segment2 
        on segment1.lEmployeeID = Segment2.lEmployeeID
        and Segment1.[Day] = Segment2.[Day]
        and Segment2.rownum = 2
    where Segment1.rowNum= 1
)
    -- make report from DailyRequest with remarks
select lEmployeeId, sFirstName, sLastName, [Day], Duration1, Duration2, BreakDuration,
    case 
    when Duration1+Duration2 >= 6 and BreakDuration = 0 then 'No Break'
    when Duration1+Duration2 >= 6 and BreakDuration < 30 then ltrim(str(coalesce(BreakDuration, 0))) +' mn break'
    when Duration1+Duration2 >= 6 and BreakDuration > 35 then ltrim(str(coalesce(BreakDuration, 0))) +' mn break'
    end as Remarks  
from DailyRequest D
```

Add `LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee` if needed (there is no use of it in your requirements, and I removed it)

Answer (score 0):

OK a shortcut for break time taken, is take the last check out and the first check in, then you have the total time clocked. The difference between that and ftc.TotalHours is the amount of break time taken. then you can add some code to report the exception.
The below code won't work if multiple days are selected, but then all we need is a date variable and add the date variable to the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT out.lEmployeeID, out.sFirstName, out.sLastName, 
CASE WHEN (out.TotalHours > 6 AND out.Break_Time_Minutes < 30) THEN 
'report exception' ELSE 0 END AS Exception_Status
FROM
( SELECT ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sFirstName, ftc.sLastName, 
ABS(DATEDIFF(mi, MAX(ftc.dtTimeOut), MIN(ftc.dtTimeIn))) - SUM(ftc.TotalHours) * 60
AS Break_Time_Minutes, SUM(ftc.TotalHours) AS TotalHours
FROM dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees AS e ON ftc.lEmployeeID = e.lEmployeeID
WHERE        (ftc.TotalHours >= 0) AND (ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) OR
(ftc.DID IS NOT NULL) AND (ftc.dtTimeOut IS NULL) 
GROUP BY ftc.lEmployeeID) as out
```